# vuetify v-flex xs12 only fill half the width

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to make list of cards using vuetify v-flex here is the code

```html
    <div id="app">
    <v-app>
    <v-content>
        <v-container fill-height fluid>
        <v-layout>
            
            <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card dark color="grey">
                <v-card-title>
                <div>
                    <h2>Top Questions</h2>
                </div>
                </v-card-title>
            </v-card>
            </v-flex>
            
            <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card v-for="item in items" :key="item._id">
                <v-card-title>
                <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{ item.content }}</p>
                </v-card-title>
            </v-card>
            </v-flex>
        </v-layout>        
        </v-container>
    </v-content>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

I am expecting each `v-flex` will fill 100% of the row. However, they only filled half of it.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mKBMEW

I can, however, add prop `d-inline-block` at v-layout. I am just curious about what happened with my first code before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add `column` attribute to `v-layout`.

Comment: thanks, that works. So what did it do exactly? why `row` attr doesn't work?

Comment: Since `v-layout` is basically a flex box, adding `column` attribute to it makes it display the items vertically which fills the available width automatically.

Answer (score 6):

When I used Ikbel's column solution, my flex-components max-width was overwritten to always be 100%. What I did is give `row wrap` attributes to `v-layout`.

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. Adding `wrap` actually solved it while I was still able to use `row` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For those who pass through this again.

In latest vuetify (from v2.x, e.g. 2.4), no longer has xs on v-col any more, use cols=12 instead.

Related post: [vuetify v-col xs="12" only fill half the width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57683550/vuetify-v-col-xs-12-only-fill-half-the-width)